# Fetching data from .csv in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a beginner, trying to understand the working of `R`. I have a `.csv` file which I read in `R` using

```
a <- read.csv(file="abc.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Now that I have the data in `a`, I have a few questions:

1. How is the data stored in `a` for eg:table, matrix, etc.
2. How can I create a matrix with only few variables of a?

These questions might be silly, but I am facing problems understanding them.

Comment: Although you asked for a matrix, it's likely the case that you still want the object to be a data.frame, which can be more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

read.csv always generates a data.frame object, which is needed to store some columns as numbers, others as text, etc.

To create a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:6),2,3) # creates 2 rows, 3 columns matrix.
```

To create a matrix with your variables:

```
m <- as.matrix(a)
```

You'll need to choose only the columns you want:

```
head(a) # show you the 5 first lines of your file, plus the column names
names(a) # show you only the column names
a1 <- a[,c(1,3:5)] # creates a new data.frame with only the 5 first columns, except the 2nd
m1 <- as.matrix(a1)
?matrix # to see more options
```

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the 'storage class' of `a`, just like any other object, by doing:

```
> class(a)
"data.frame"
```

... then you can get help on `data.frame` with:

```
> help(data.frame)
```

or using the package help (PDF or HTML) or online help.

Please read the manuals: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html

There you will find your answers:

- [3.1 Intrinsic attributes (of objects): mode and length](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-intrinsic-attributes-mode-and-length)
- [6.3 Data frames](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Data-frames)

Comment: You can also do '?data.frame' and '??data.frame' to get help.